# Next Without For?

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm sure this has been asked a hundred times, and I've compared it to other ones like it, but I don't see the problem in my code. Now it's getting all the way down to "Next oOccurrence" and I get a "Next Without For" error. I don't see it...do you?

```
Option Explicit
Public i As Integer

Sub ReplaceComponent()
Dim NameStr As String
Dim NewNamePath As String

Dim NameStr2 As String
Dim OldNamePath As String

For i = 0 To 99 Step 1

NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text               'Concatenates the full new file path
NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text      'Concatenates the old file NAME
OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"


Dim oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence               'Creates a ton of errors that have been giving me a headache
For Each oOccurrence In ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences
    If oOccurrence.ReferencedDocumentDescriptor.FullDocumentName = OldNamePath Then
    oOccurrence.Replace NewNamePath, True
Exit For
    End If

    If i = 99 Then
DeletetheDirectory                            'When i = 99, deletes the temporary directory
                                              'Will save the file
                                              'Will close the file
Resolve_and_Open.Show vbModal                 'Reopens form 3 to select the next assembly
    Else: Next oOccurrence
    Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you can't do it in that way: `Else: Next i`. And also this make no sence to me `Else: Next oOccurrence` and next line `Next i`. What are you going to achive using thouse lines?

Comment: Edited it back to how it was before I started messing with it more. I'm just trying to get it to go to the next occurrence of a part (say there are two of the same part in a group) to replace, and then move to the next i. So let's say there are two of PrettyPonies-001 and one PrettyPonies-002. They used to be called UglyPonies-001 and UglyPonies-002. The program goes in and replaces UglyPonies-001 with PrettyPonies-001, moves to the next occurrence of PrettyPonies-001 and changes that, and then adds i + 1 and looks for UglyPonies-002 to replace with PrettyPonies-002.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by `Else: Next oOccurrence`, `Next i`, so I'm sure the compiler doesn't either.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? Did I not define it right or something? I'm fairly new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is simply that you have End If after Next i. You should close If i = 99 first, and there is no need for the Else at all, since you should loop regardless of whether i = 99 or not.

```
    If i = 99 Then
        DeletetheDirectory                                          
        Resolve_and_Open.Show vbModal               
    End if
    Next oOccurrence
Next i
```

Comment: Well that cleared that error. Opened a whole new problem, but it cleared that error :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but maybe the following reformatting will help.

I can't run your code because I don't know what Renamer is. Can you just explain the two loops and what you when you would like them to end?

```
Option Explicit
Public i As Integer

Sub ReplaceComponent()
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim NewNamePath As String

    Dim NameStr2 As String
    Dim OldNamePath As String

    For i = 0 To 99 Step 1

        'Concatenates the full new file path
        NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text
        NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

        'Concatenates the old file NAME
        NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text
        OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

        'Creates a ton of errors that have been giving me a headache
        Dim invAD
        Set invAD = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument
        Dim oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence
        Set oOccurrence = invAD.ComponentDefinition.ActiveOccurrence

        For Each oOccurrence In ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences
            If oOccurrence.ReferencedDocumentDescriptor.FullDocumentName = OldNamePath Then
                oOccurrence.Replace NewNamePath, True
                Exit For
            End If

            If i = 99 Then
                'When i = 99, deletes the temporary directory
                DeletetheDirectory

                'Reopens form 3 to select the next assembly
                Resolve_and_Open.Show vbModal
                Exit For
            End If
        Next oOccurrence
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: "... I'm just trying to get it to go to the next occurrence of a part (say there are two of the same part in a group) to replace, and then move to the next i. So let's say there are two of PrettyPonies-001 and one PrettyPonies-002. They used to be called UglyPonies-001 and UglyPonies-002. The program goes in and replaces UglyPonies-001 with PrettyPonies-001, moves to the next occurrence of PrettyPonies-001 and changes that, and then adds i + 1 and looks for UglyPonies-002 to replace with PrettyPonies-002." Does that answer

Comment: your question? Renamer is a form that renames those files. It's referencing the old and new prefix names and concatenates their path/file names from there :)

Comment: When I run your version it brings me back to my original problem (posted in another question) where I get a run-time 91 error claiming that oOccurrence is not set. The loop of errors will never end hahaha

Comment: I'm not sure what `ComponentOccurrence` but it doesn't look like it is ever set with a new instance. Try `Dim oOccurrence As New ComponentOccurrence`

Comment: It knows ComponentOccurrence :) It's in the library already. I did try that anyways though and it let me know that it didn't like my trying to add something new

Comment: Can you try my edited code above. I've never used AutoCAD so not sure exactly of the documentation, but it certainly does look like oOccurrence is never set to an instance of anything.

Comment: Variable not defined...what is invAD?

Comment: Sorry I didn't declare the variable. Can you try one more time please. Also take a look at this article, which seems to be doing something similar to what you are doing: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/2012/08/replace-a-componentoccurrence-in-a-sub-assembly.html

Comment: I sure wish I could. The article is blocked at my work place. I got a run-time error 91 on this line: `Set oOccurrence = invAD.ComponentDefinition.ActiveOccurrence` I am quite stumped about this. Thank you so much for trying. Do you think it isn't a "Next Without For" problem afterall?

Comment: Alright I went to our IT guy and got a printed copy of the article. I'm still playing with it, but I'm getting the same errors so far. Thanks for helping me out!